# Patching ActiveRecord to add dynamic, attribute-based methods to all models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to see if it would be possible to add a few more "magic" methods to `ActiveRecord::Base`. For example, by default we're given methods like `[attribute]_changed?` and `[attribute]_was` methods. I would like to hook into ActiveRecord such that I can access the attribute names and dynamically add `[attribute]?` aliases for `[attribute]_at?` attributes.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I was thinking more for other timestamp attributes -- so `scheduled?` would be an alias to `scheduled_at?`... I suppose it would only be useful for attributes where it's allowed to be nil.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you don't "Patch" Active Record. Simply define the convenience methods you require in your models. While a dynamic solution that you are proposing might offer some theoretical future convenience (for example not having to specify additional methods in future), it will be a bit of trade off between easily readable / maintainable code.

If you want to sacrifice readability for this convenience, and the behaviour will apply to multiple classes then you could implement as a module / library and include in your models. This module might live in the model concerns directory for example.

Another way could be to create a base class that your models inherit from which in turn inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`. If you opt for a dynamic solution, I would still recommend that you implement in such a way that it is obvious what you are doing. Hiding away any unconventional implementation is going to be a pain for anyone in future trying to understand your code.

Stick to well known conventions and prioritise readability over convenience. A hint to how you would implement a dynamic solution lies in meta programming which you can [Google](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=ruby%20metaprogramming)

This answer is obviously very opinionated, but I hope it offers some good food for thought!